# Security risks with setDomStorageEnabled(true) in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, dom

What are the security risks associated with enabling `setDomStorageEnabled(true)` method?

[Reference.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled(boolean))

Comment: Are you worried about any specific security risk, or are you just asking more generally if there are any?

Comment: @Anders generally want to know about all aspects, what could be the possible cases.

Comment: Localstorage should not be used for storing credentials.  It's designed to be used for client-side storage where the values are never sent to the server.  (Good for GUI variables... size, themes, etc...)  The default of "false" would prevent people from storing sensitive information there so it's a little safer if the coders aren't very good with security.  You could, for instance, craft an XSS attack to send all the localstorage for the site to a 3rd party URL.

Comment: It may also open a vector whereby the attacker uses localstorage to store their own objects for retrieval later.  createObjectURL()  (Or even file creation through XSS?  Is that possible?  Seems like the user would see the download happen, but might out of curiosity run it?)

Answer (score 0):

The DOM storage control is set to true, which allows the application to store page elements that could include user sensitive information. Setting the DOM Storage value to false will prevents local storage from being used.